# Rendering Partial Collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

[Section 7.1 Rendering Partial Collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#rendering-partial-collections) has us looping through an array of 'comments' that belong to a 'post', and rendering a partial as the result. I can't get my head around this one.

In "views/posts/show.html.erb" we have this code:

```
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

Since a `@post` has multiple comments, this somehow knows to use the partial in `views/comments/_comment.html.erb`. How is this possible? Will Rails singularize "comments" into "comment"?

Even if Rails knows to singularize "comments" into "comment", how does Rails know to look into `views/comments/_comment.html.erb` and not `views/posts/_comment.html.erb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the magic of Rails.  Because you have a `comment.rb` model, which probably `belongs_to :post`, it knows that `@post.comments` is a collection of comments.  You can do a lot with it, too.  Say you wanted to use a different partial, you could do

```
# render a bunch of @images with a different partial
<%= render partial: 'images/_preview', collection: @images %> 

# render a partial with a different object than assigned (since images are looking for an 'image' variable inside of an _image file)
<%= render 'images/preview', preview: @image %>
```

So... yeah.  The naming conventions are part of what keeps Ruby 'on Rails'.

Comment: Interesting. So an object is linked to a partial view that has the same name like the model `boot` would create a view `views/boots/_boot.html.erb`?

Comment: Well no.  When you create a controller, that's what creates the matching view.  You have to know some of the magic words at that point.  Rails is very 'namey' though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to RoR I think that you have a hell of such questions ahead ;) I *think* that 'render' method does not get any '@post.comments' string to its input, but proxy collection of Comment objects, so there is no singularization (uff) of string happens here. After that it looks at input: "ok, collection of comments, let's look if there any '_comment' partial in views/comments/ path... oh here it is!" ) automagically!